# Insert a Variable inside simple quotation marks PHP

Tags: php

How i can use a variable ($_REQUEST('subject')) inside simple quotation marks.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$uri = 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json';

$postString = '{//i can't quit this quotation mark
"key": "myapi",
"message": {
    "html": "this is the emails html content",
    "subject": "$_REQUEST['subject'];",//this dont work
    "from_email": "email@mydomain.com",
    "from_name": "John",
    "to": [
        {
            "email": "test@hotmail.com",
            "name": "Bob"
        }
    ],
    "headers": {
    },
    "auto_text": true
},
"async": false
}';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `"subject": "$_REQUEST['subject'];"` to `"subject": "' . $_REQUEST['subject'] . '"`

Comment: You should also be sanitizing the data in the $_REQUEST variable.

Answer (score 1):

That's JSON! Use [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) and [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)!

```
$json = json_decode ($postString, true); // true for the second parameter forces associative arrays 

$json['message']['subject'] = json_encode ($_REQUEST);

$postString = json_encode ($json);
```

Although, it looks like you could save a step and yourself some trouble if you just build `$postString` as a regular php array.

```
$postArr = array (
"key" => "myapi",
"message" => array (
    "html" => "this is the emails html content",
    "subject" => $_REQUEST['subject'],
    "from_email" =>  "email@mydomain.com",
    "from_name" => "John",
    "to" => array (
        array (
            "email" => "test@hotmail.com",
            "name" => "Bob"
        )
    ),
    "headers" => array (),
    "auto_text" => true
),
"async" => false
);

$postString = json_encode ($postArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$postString = '{
   "key": "myapi",
   "message": {
      "html": "this is the emails html content",
      "subject": "'.$_REQUEST['subject'].'",       // Modify this way
      "from_email": "email@mydomain.com",
      "from_name": "John",
    ....
    .....
}';
```